# Are books published by companies such as Pearson and Wiley typed via latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, pgfplots

Regarding the figures in them, are they designed by them ? 
how did they get such a high quality of pictures, figures and charts?

Comment: I know that the Springer book are done in tex

Comment: I am not sure if this question is on-topic. Maybe you should ask the publisher directly.

Comment: @valerie It seems most introductory books are done using Adobe creative suite and most graduate level books only use latex without all the "useless" designs and colors.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Exactly in 2010 I was interested in how the books of Mathematics, Physics, Chemistry are written, and on the cover there is also written a supporting publishing house. I can give you any information at 360°.

Comment: Have you ever tried to contact them?

Comment: @Sebastiano Didn't know that. I worked with designers a few years ago (I was an editor) but couldn't convince them to use latex to type equations. They did it directly in InDesign: it took a lot of time to write an equation and it didn't look beautiful. At least they're better than the ones using MS word.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a question with an objective answer. The publishers likely use a range of tools, depending on the series, authors, history, etc., and in any case, unless they say explicitly how any particular text is set, we can't know. (The only time one sees the info tends to be where an author has done the typesetting themselves, when often they do tell us its LaTeX).

Comment: My book (With Doug Schenck) *Information Modeling: The EXPRESS Way" was published by Oxford University Press from our LaTeX to PDF source.